# Is it theoretically possible to use `putRecord` in Kinesis via singular http POST request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

I've been experiencing some issues with AWS Kinesis inasmuch as I have a stream set up and I want to use a standard http `POST` request to invoke a Kinesis PutRecord call on my stream. I'm doing this because bundle-size of my resultant javascript application matters and I'd rather not import the `aws-sdk` to accomplish something that should (on paper) be possible.

Just so you know, I've looked at [this other stack overflow question about the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39939225/call-rest-api-for-amazon-kinesis-with-setting-up-api-gateway) and It was... sort of informational.

Now, I already have a method to sigv4 sign a request using an access key, secret token, and session token. but when I finally get the result of signing the request and send it using the in-browser `fetch` api, the service tanks with  (or with a json object citing the same thing, depending on my Content-Type header, I guess) as the result.

Here's the code I'm working with

```
// There is a global function "sign" that does sigv4 signing
// ...

var payload = {
    Data: { task: "Get something working in kinesis" },
    PartitionKey: "1",
    StreamName: "MyKinesisStream"
}

var credentials =  {
    "accessKeyId": "<access.key>",
    "secretAccessKey": "<secret.key>",
    "sessionToken": "<session.token>",
    "expiration": 1528922673000
}

function signer({ url, method, data }) {
    // Wrapping with URL for piecemeal picking of parsed pieces
    const parsed = new URL(url);

    const [ service, region ] = parsed.host.split(".");

    const signed = sign({
        method,
        service,
        region,
        url,

        // Hardcoded
        headers : {
            Host           : parsed.host,
            "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=UTF-8",

            "X-Amz-Target" : "Kinesis_20131202.PutRecord"
        },

        body : JSON.stringify(data),
    }, credentials);

    return signed;
}

// Specify method, url, data body
var signed = signer({
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
    data : JSON.stringify(payload)
});

var request = fetch(signed.url, signed);
```

When I look at the result of request, I get this:

```
{
    Output: { 
       __type: "com.amazon.coral.service#InternalFailure"},
       Version: "1.0" 
}
```

Now I'm unsure as to whether Kinesis is actually failing here, or if my input is malformed?

here's what the signed request looks like

```
{
    "method": "POST",
    "service": "kinesis",
    "region": "us-west-2",
    "url": "https://kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
    "headers": {
        "Host": "kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "X-Amz-Target": "Kinesis_20131202.PutRecord",
        "X-Amz-Date": "20180613T203123Z",
        "X-Amz-Security-Token": "<session.token>",
        "Authorization": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<access.key>/20180613/us-west-2/kinesis/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-target, Signature=ba20abb21763e5c8e913527c95a0c7efba590cf5ff1df3b770d4d9b945a10481"
    },
    "body": "\"{\\\"Data\\\":{\\\"task\\\":\\\"Get something working in kinesis\\\"},\\\"PartitionKey\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"StreamName\\\":\\\"MyKinesisStream\\\"}\"",
    "test": {
        "canonical": "POST\n/\n\ncontent-type:application/json; charset=UTF-8\nhost:kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-target:Kinesis_20131202.PutRecord\n\ncontent-type;host;x-amz-target\n508d2454044bffc25250f554c7b4c8f2e0c87c2d194676c8787867662633652a",
        "sts": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20180613T203123Z\n20180613/us-west-2/kinesis/aws4_request\n46a252f4eef52991c4a0903ab63bca86ec1aba09d4275dd8f5eb6fcc8d761211",
        "auth": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<access.key>/20180613/us-west-2/kinesis/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-target, Signature=ba20abb21763e5c8e913527c95a0c7efba590cf5ff1df3b770d4d9b945a10481"
    }
```

(the test key is used by the library that generates the signature, so ignore that)
(Also there are probably extra slashes in the body because I pretty printed the response object using JSON.stringify).

My question: Is there something I'm missing? Does Kinesis require headers a, b, and c and I'm only generating two of them? Or is this internal error an actual failure. I'm lost because the response suggests nothing I can do on my end.

I appreciate any help!

Edit: As a secondary question, am I using the `X-Amz-Target` header correctly? This **is** how you reference calling a service function so long as you're hitting that service endpoint, no?

**Update**: Followinh Michael's comments, I've gotten somewhere, but I still haven't solved the problem. Here's what I did:

I made sure that in my `payload` I'm only running `JSON.stringify` on the `Data` property.

I also modified the `Content-Type` header to be `"Content-Type" : "application/x-amz-json-1.1"` and as such, I'm getting slightly more useful error messages back.

Now, my payload is still mostly the same:

```
var payload = {
    Data: JSON.stringify({ task: "Get something working in kinesis" }),
    PartitionKey: "1",
    StreamName: "MyKinesisStream"
}
```

and my signer function body looks like this:

```
 function signer({ url, method, data }) {
    // Wrapping with URL for piecemeal picking of parsed pieces
    const parsed = new URL(url);

    const [ service, region ] = parsed.host.split(".");

    const signed = sign({
        method,
        service,
        region,
        url,

        // Hardcoded
        headers : {
            Host           : parsed.host,
            "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=UTF-8",

            "X-Amz-Target" : "Kinesis_20131202.PutRecord"
        },

        body : data,
    }, credentials);

    return signed;
}
```

So I'm passing in an object that is partially serialized (at least Data is) and when I send this to the service, I get a response of:

`{"__type":"SerializationException"}`

which is at least *marginally helpful* because it tells me that my input is technically incorrect. However, I've done a few things in an attempt to correct this:

- I've run `JSON.stringify` on the entire payload
- I've changed my `Data` key to just be a string value to see if it would go through
- I've tried running `JSON.stringify` on Data and then running `btoa` because I read on another post that that worked for someone.

But I'm still getting the same error. I feel like I'm *so close*. Can you spot anything I might be missing or something I haven't tried? I've gotten sporadic unknownoperationexceptions but I think right now this Serialization has me stumped.

**Edit 2:**

As it turns out, Kinesis will only accept a `base64` encoded string. This is probably a nicety that the `aws-sdk` provides, but essentially all it took was `Data: btoa(JSON.stringify({ task: "data"}))` in the payload to get it working

Comment: Some of the "extra slashes" are because you are incorrectly stringifying the body twice.  `body: JSON.stringify(data)` should just be `body: data` because earlier, you already created a JSON object with `data: JSON.stringify(payload)`.

Comment: Caught that. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not certain this is the only issue, it seems like you are sending a request body that contains an incorrectly serialized (double-encoded) payload.

```
var obj = { foo: 'bar'};
```

JSON.stringify(obj) returns a string...

```
'{"foo": "bar"}' // the ' are not part of the string, I'm using them to illustrate that this is a thing of type string.
```

...and when parsed with a JSON parser, this **returns an object**.

```
{ foo: 'bar' }
```

However, JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(obj)) returns a different string...

```
'"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"'
```

...but when parsed, this **returns a string**.

```
 '{"foo": "bar"}'
```

The service endpoint expects to parse the body and get an object, not a string... so, parsing the request body (from the service's perspective) doesn't return the correct *type*.  The error seems to be a failure of the service to parse your request at a very low level.

In your code, `body: JSON.stringify(data)` should just be `body: data` because earlier, you already created a JSON object with `data: JSON.stringify(payload)`.

As written, you are effectively setting `body` to JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(payload)).

Comment: Ah! noted. I think that solves one problem and introduces another. The good news: I'm no longer receiving an `InternalFailure`, the bad news: I'm now receiving an `UnknownOperationException` which leads me to believe the `X-Amz-Target` either isn't supported or it's some sort of bad input.

Comment: @Morklympious I think your action is correct, but your `Data` inside `Payload` is wrong.  *That* is supposed to be a string, not an object... so  `var payload = {
    Data: "Get something working in kinesis", ...` or `var payload = {
    Data: JSON.stringify( { task: "Get something working in kinesis" } ),...`

Comment: Michael, I really appreciate all the help. This is helping me figure some things out. I've updated the post with things I've tried. I modified content type headers and it looks like they're at least giving me more useful error output, but I'm still a little stuck!

Comment: You can always try `aws kinesis put-record ... --debug` with aws-cli and see if it generates enough output information to show you what they are doing differently than you.

Comment: As it turns out, Kinesis will only accept a base64 encoded string. This is probably a nicety that the `aws-sdk` provides, but essentially all it took was `Data: btoa(JSON.stringify({ task: "data"}))` to get it working.

Comment: @Morklympious I completely missed that.  You're correct.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you ever figured this out, but this question pops up on Google when searching for how to do this. The one piece I think you are missing is that the Record Data field must be base64 encoded. Here's a chunk of NodeJS code that will do this (using PutRecords).

And for anyone asking, why not just use the SDK? I currently must stream data from a cluster that cannot be updated to a NodeJS version that the SDK requires due to other dependencies. Yay.

```
const https = require('https')
const aws4  = require('aws4')
const request = function(o) { https.request(o, function(res) { res.pipe(process.stdout) }).end(o.body || '') }

const _publish_kinesis = function(logs) {
    const kin_logs = logs.map(function (l) {
        let blob = JSON.stringify(l) + '\n'
        let buff = Buffer.from(blob, 'binary');
        let base64data = buff.toString('base64');

        return {
            Data: base64data,
            PartitionKey: '0000'
        }
    })

    while(kin_logs.length > 0) {
        let data = JSON.stringify({
            Records: kin_logs.splice(0,250),
            StreamName: 'your-streamname'
        })

        let _request = aws4.sign({
            hostname: 'kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
            method: 'POST',
            body: data,
            path: '/?Action=PutRecords',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
                'X-Amz-Target': 'Kinesis_20131202.PutRecords'
            },
         }, {
            secretAccessKey: "****",
            accessKeyId: "****"
           // sessionToken: "<your-session-token>"
         })

        request(_request)
    }
}

var logs = [{
  'timeStamp': new Date().toISOString(),
  'value': 'test02',
},{
  'timeStamp': new Date().toISOString(),
  'value': 'test01',
}]
_publish_kinesis(logs)
```

Comment: I now see you commented on the above answer noting that base64 encoding requirement. Well, I'll leave this here as a complete answer.